# mixing flexbox and fixed/absolute positioning

Tags: css

I have a site where at the top level I have several components and I want them to be responsive. So I have them in a flex box. One or more of these components I want to have the items within it to be fixed.  More specifically my app is a card game, so I have a play area, a chat area, score pad.  I have these in a flexbox, the chat and scorepad are also responsive. But the play area I have with fixed or absolute positions. My issues is when I make the play area either fixed or absolution the chat area and play area are both in  the same place around 0,0.  I want the cordiates in the play area to be relative to its bounding Div not to the viewport.

How do I set up the top components and the child components.

Comment: Please show your code so we can see the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want the cordiates in the play area to be relative to its bounding Div not to the viewport."

You can make a child element be positioned absolute relative to its parent container rather than the viewport by adding "position: relative" to the parent and "position: absolute" to the child. This will make the child be positioned relative to its parent.

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but I hope this gives some guidance, it would be advised to provide some sort of code that can be replicated so others can better help you solve your issue.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">child element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it, I was thinking they position attribute applied to the children of the container but it really is only for itself. Now it makes more sense

Comment: No problem, glad it helped (= Happy coding!